Confusion regarding how God punishes sin in light of 1 Samuel 3:11
The main issue I have stems with 1 Samuel 3:11-14 and 1 Samuel 2:31-33

11 And the Lord said to Samuel: “See, I am about to do something in
Israel that will make the ears of everyone who hears about it tingle.
12 At that time I will carry out against Eli everything I spoke
against his family—from beginning to end. 13 For I told him that I
would judge his family forever because of the sin he knew about; his
sons blasphemed God, and he failed to restrain them. 14 Therefore I
swore to the house of Eli, ‘The guilt of Eli’s house will never be
atoned for by sacrifice or offering.’”

in the previous chapter it also says:

"31 The time is coming when I will cut short your strength and the
strength of your priestly house, so that no one in it will reach old
age, 32 and you will see distress in my dwelling. Although good will
be done to Israel, no one in your family line will ever reach old age.
33 Every one of you that I do not cut off from serving at my altar I
will spare only to destroy your sight and sap your strength, and all
your descendants will die in the prime of life.

In Ezekiel 18 it says:

19 “Yet you ask, ‘Why does the son not share the guilt of his father?’
Since the son has done what is just and right and has been careful to
keep all my decrees, he will surely live. 20 The one who sins is the
one who will die. The child will not share the guilt of the parent,
nor will the parent share the guilt of the child. The righteousness of
the righteous will be credited to them, and the wickedness of the
wicked will be charged against them.

Maybe I'm taking these out of context but this is genuinely confusing to me, If God in Ezekiel says he wont kill the children of those who sin, why do the descendants of Eli have exclusion from the sacrifices and they wont see old age? This feels like it would be a death sentence but What are your thoughts?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for this excellent question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site works.

The problem is even more profound than the OP suggests.
In Eze 18 we have the important legal principle that children are NOT held responsible for the guilt of their parents and vis-versa.
However, in Ex 20:5 we have clear statement that:

for I, the LORD your God, am a jealous God, visiting the iniquity of
the fathers on their children to the third and fourth generations of
those who hate Me

What is going on here?  Which is correct?  I will now show that both are correct because each is discussing different things, and the family of Eli is a perfect illustration of this distinction.
1. Eli
Eli was a priest and father and judge of Israel.  As a father, his great sin was not raising his sons to truly fear the LORD - they were supremely wicked (1 Sam 2:12).  This set up a chain of events that had disastrous consequences for the subsequent generations.  Eli died when he heard that his sons were killed in battle. 1 Sam 4:18.  Thus, Eli bore the consequences of his own sins.
2. Eli's sons, Hophni and Phineas
As stated above, Hophni and Phineas, the two sons of Eli were wicked priests serving in the Sanctuary - they slept with the women and embezzled the offerings at the temple.  Their final act of blasphemy was taking the Ark of the Covenant into battle, 1 Sam 4:1-11.  This directly resulted in their deaths.  They died as a consequence of their own sins.
3. Ahimelech
It is not certain, but it appears that Ahimelech may have taken the priesthood following the triple deaths of Eli and his two sons on the same day.  In any case, he was priest during the time of Saul and was brutally murdered, on the orders of Saul in the town of Nob by Doeg. 1 Sam 21, 22.  Only his son Abiathar escaped with David's men.
4. Abiathar
When Abiathar escaped with David's men during the priestly anarchy that followed the massacre of priests at Nob, he took the Ephod and effectively became High Priest.  However, later in his life he became involved in sedition & treason by supporting the rebellion of Adonijah (1 Kings 1).  Subsequently, Solomon deposed Abiathar as high priest and banned his family from ever being priests; Zadok was installed as High Priest.  1 Sam 2:26, 27.  Thus Abiathar was punished for his own sin.
Concerning the lack of sacrifice for sin, the Pulpit commentary offers in about 1 Sam 1:14 -

Verse 14. - Sacrifice nor offering. The first of these is zebach, the sacrifice of an animal by the shedding of its blood; the second is
the minchah, or unbloody sacrifice. The guilt of Eli's sons could be
purged, i.e. expiated, by none of the appointed offerings for sin,
because they had hardened themselves in their wrong doing even after
the solemn warning in 1 Samuel 2:27-36. Hence the marked repetition of
the denunciation of finality in their doom. Again it is said that it
is forever. It has, however, been well noticed that though the message
of Samuel confirms all that had been threatened by the man of God, yet
that no bitter or painful words are put into the mouth of one who was
still a child. For this there may also be a further reason. The first
message was intended to give Eli and his sons a final opportunity of
repentance, and, that it might produce its full effect, the severity
of the doom impending upon them was clearly set before their eyes.
They did not repent. Eli hardened himself in his weakness, and took no
steps to vindicate God's service from the slur cast upon it by an
unworthy priesthood. His sons hardened themselves in crime, and made
their office a reproach. It was enough, therefore, to repeat and
confirm generally the terms of the former prophecy, as no moral object
would be gained by calling attention to the severity of the coming
judgment. 1 Samuel 3:14

CONCLUSION
Thus, we have shown that each sinful person became responsible for his own sin and the prophecy in 1 Sam 2 about Eli's descendants was a simple statement of fact.
Therefore, the guilt of the fathers was not visited as a punishment on the sons; however, the series of consequences of their actions often takes generations to bare full fruit.  That is, while we do not inherit guilt, we do inherit sinful weaknesses and tendencies to evil.
The problem can also be seen in an even wider form - we are not held responsible for Adam's sin; BUT we have inherited Adam's sinful nature - a point discussed at length in Rom 5:12-21.

What do we do with the language though that the temple sacrifices wont atone for their sin? He says the house, did his lineage end there or if it continued would this mean that none of them had a means to atone for their sins at all or just the sin of their ancestors?

@william - it probably refers to the fact that the high priestly line would be extinguished from his lineage and never be restored.  This was the case.

appreciated, thank you. This helps a lot.

My edit was merely changing 1 typo. But I would add here that to say "we do inherit sinful weaknesses and tendencies to evil" quite shocks me. That is a gross minimisation as to what inheriting Adam's sinful nature really means, as Romans chapter 2 to 8 explains. Otherwise, a good answer.

@Anne - many thanks for your kindness in correcting my typo.  I was trying to use technical language in the light of Rom 3:10-18 makes clear.  I am old enough to know from bitter experience that all people have inherited a sinful nature that can become extremely depraved in anyone, but for the transforming grace of God.

I just want to say that this answer is excellent. It  deserves a gold star in addition to an upvote!

@DanFefferman - many thanks for your kind generosity.

I'd include this as an addendum to @Dottard's answer. God was making major changes around this time, preparing to shift the providence from the tribal level (judges and the Tabernacle) to the national level (kings centered on the Temple). A corrupt priesthood could not lead this process. The sins of Eli's sons were extremely serious and he himself was judged by God to be personally corrupt in his own right. His sin was not only that he failed to raise his sons properly. Just after we are informed of the sins of Eli's sins we find this:

A man of God came to Eli and said to him: “Thus says the Lord... I assigned all the
fire offerings of the Israelites to your father’s house. 29 Why do you
stare greedily at my sacrifices and at the offerings that I have
prescribed? Why do you honor your sons more than you honor me,
fattening yourselves with the choicest part of every offering of my
people Israel?

Conclusion:  God judged Eli himself to be corrupt, as well as his sons. We conclude that he was punished for his own sins, not those of his sons or even his failure to raise them properly. In the meantime God had raised up Samuel in Eli's household to lead his providence to the national level centered on King Saul and later King David.
